# Modifying a drive files permission with Drive.Permissions.insert error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a trigger that executes when a Google form is submitted. When the form is submitted, it creates a document. I want to have the trigger script add a user to be able to view the file.

My Code:

```
function onSubmitter(e){
  var user = e.namedValues['Shareholder Name:'][0];
  var email = e.namedValues['Shareholder Email:'][0];
  var proxy1 = e.namedValues['1ST PROXY NOMINEE:'][0];  
  var proxy2 = e.namedValues['2ND PROXY NOMINEE:'][0];
  var attendance = e.namedValues['ATTENDANCE:'][0];
  var arrival = e.namedValues['ARRIVAL DATE:'][0];
  var departure = e.namedValues['DEPARTURE DATE:'][0];
  var certification = e.namedValues['CERTIFICATION:'][0];
  var electronicsignature = e.namedValues['ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE:'][0];
  var rowstart = e.range.getRow();
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var pdflink = activeSheet.getRange(rowstart, 14).getValue();

  var fileID = pdflink.toString().replace("https://drive.google.com/a/xxxxxx/file/d/", "");
  fileID = fileID.toString().replace("/view?usp=drivesdk", "");


  var id = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var idtwo = id.getId();

  Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'reader',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': email
   },
   idtwo,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });

  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email_proxy');
        templ.shareholderAccount = user;
        templ.shareholderLink = pdflink;
        templ.shareholderFriendlyName = user;

  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Proxy Confirmation', '',{
         htmlBody: message
       });
```

The error I get:

> API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: The authenticated user has not granted the app 280983214043111 write access to the file 1GI0psQysSE9xuzs3W3vNs99qcCFSUUsF4T
>       at onSubmitter(Trigger:48)**

I thought since the app runs under my user account and I have access to the files that it would have the right permissions.  I'm guessing not given it's being invoked by a trigger?

Any idea how I give my app the ability to have write access to all files in my Drive?  I can run this code directly and it works, just not when invoked by the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

### I am not sure how you create the file, but the following code works for me without error on form submit:

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.createFile("name", "content");
  var email = "foo@gmail.com";
  var fileID=file.getId();

  Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'reader',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': email
   },
   fileID,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
}
```

If this code also works for you, but your own code does not - please provide the rest of your code for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The code above works for me as well when I run it directly.  However, it doesn't work when I execute it from a trigger event, OnSubmit form.  That's when I get the permission error saying my app doesn't have access to change permission on the file.  Hope that make sense:

Comment: I also execute it on form submit trigger and it works for me. Did you bind the script to your Form (opposed to the destination spreadsheet)?

Comment: the code you provided works for me as well.  i can also execute my code directly.  it only errors with the error i provided above when it's executed by the trigger I have it setup within.  does that help?

Comment: If my code works for you, but yours doesn't - I would need to see the rest of your code (please remove private data). It is likely that you implemented some request that does not have the authorization to run on trigger.

Comment: folks, thanks for the help.  figured it out.  there was a permission issue at the GSuite level.